# Error while running the sample display image program in python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting an error when I run the following sample display image program in my Dell Inspiron 15R windows 8.1 64 bit system

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('G:/space.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the error which I am getting at the command prompt is:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Ankit>python G:/messi.py
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in unknown function, file C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2482
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "G:/messi.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> cv2.imshow('image',img)
> ```
>
> cv2.error:
>   C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2
>
> 482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type

Please help! I am a novice in opencv.

Comment: Maybe the image couldn't be read. You might want to `print img` to check if it's valid. See [the `imread` documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I replaced .jpg formatted image with other .bmp formatted image and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the image couldn't be read. You might want to `print img` to check if it's valid. See [the `imread` documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) for more information.

Comment: I copied my comment into a community wiki answer to mark this question as answered.